# Pegar valor do input date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho dois input date criado, e gostaria de pegar a data dos dois por um botão.

```
            <div class='col-md-5 col-lg-4'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Inicio</span>
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'><span></span>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class='col-md-5 col-lg-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
                <span>Fim</span>
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
        <div id="espaco"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" onclick = "botaoFunfa>
              Buscar
            </button>
    </div>
```

Toda vez que tento pegar ele mostra o código e nao o valor

JS

```
function botaoFunfa() {
    var teste = document.querySelector("#datetimepicker6");
    console.log(teste);
}
```

Eu consegui pegar o valor da seguinte forma:

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
function botaoFunfa() {
    var teste = document.querySelector(".switch");
    var StringData = teste.textContent || teste.innerText; 
    console.log(StringData);
}
```

Assim ele mostrara o dia, mês e ano. Obs.: a classe switch é do próprio bootstrap.

Mas por algum motivo ta dando algum bug, e ele nao pega os dois input date, apenas um.

Comment: tente com `var teste = document.querySelector("#datetimepicker6").value;`

Comment: Consegui resolver colocando puxando a classe switch, mas nao pega os dois e da erro

Comment: `datetimepicker6` não possui uma propriedade `value`, repare que o `id` está em uma `div`, se você quer obter o `value` de um elemento `input` por seu `id`. Você deve primeiramente informar o `id` no HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma solução abaixo, apenas busca o `val()` de cada um ao botão ser clicado.

```js
    
    $('#btn').click(function(){
      var inicio = $('#inicio').val(),
      fim = $('#fim').val();       
       console.log('data inicial: ' + inicio + ' data final: ' +fim);
       
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class='col-md-5 col-lg-4'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span>Inicio</span>
                        <div class='input-group date' ><span></span>
                                <input id='inicio' type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class='col-md-5 col-lg-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
                <span>Fim</span>
            <div class='input-group date' >
                <input id='fim' type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
        <div id="espaco"></div>
            <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" >
              Buscar
            </button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```